# how to use pyinstaller to make the app run with admin on Linux ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pyinstaller

Tried to use `pyinstaller -F --uac-admin main.py`
I have to run the `./dist/main` with `sudo`. If I don't use `sudo` or just double click on the app icon. The app didn't run at all.

(No manifest file in build/main/ on Linux).

the main.spec shows `uac_admin=True`.

Also tried to use `chmod +x main`. not works.